# Nginx HTTPS Connection refused

Tags: ssl, nginx, https, connection-refused

I'm having trouble getting SSL to work with my Nginx installation. I found a couple of other questions related to this but they did not fix my problem.

Checks I did:

- `nginx -t` returns with no errors
- `ufw disable` to let all traffic trough
- `netstat -nltp` tells me that `tcp:0.0.0.0:80` and `tcp:0.0.0.0:433` go to `nginx: master`
- `curl -v https://mywebsite.nl` returns `Failed to connect to mywebsite.nl port 443: Connection refused`
- `curl -v http://mywebsite.nl` returns OK

Weird things:

- `netstat -peanut | grep ":80 "` returns with `tcp:0.0.0.0:80` bound to `nginx: master` but when I try `netstat -peanut | grep ":443 "` it returns nothing?
- if I try `nmap -p 433 mywebsite.nl` it returns `433/tcp filtered nnsp` while I expected the port to be open as it does with port 80

I bundled my CA certificate together with my own one (in the right order as mentioned by the Nginx docs).

My Nginx-conf looks like this:

```
server {
listen 80;
listen 433 ssl http2;

ssl_certificate             /etc/ssl/certs/mywebsite.nl-bundle.crt;
ssl_certificate_key         /etc/ssl/certs/mywebsite.nl.key;

server_name                 *.mywebsite.nl;
root                        /var/www/mywebsite-app/public;

add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";

index index.php;

charset utf-8;

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}

location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

error_page 404 /index.php;

location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
}

location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
    deny all;
}

if ($scheme != "https") {
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> listen 433 ssl http2;

It should be 443, not 433. See also the error message, which also says that it tries to connect to port 443:

> Failed to connect to covidtesta4.nl port 443: Connection refused

Comment: Thank you very much, I feel a little stupid now. It goes to show how quickly someone can overlook a single number.